# Can I Delete those Default users?

Tags: ckan

Can I delete those users without any problems:

visitor, logged_in, default

I did not find any reference to those Users specificly in the source code

my ckan version:
ckan 2.5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'visitor' and 'logged_in' were pseudo-users, used by the role-based-auth system in CKAN before version 2.0. They were created automatically in those old CKAN versions. If you're now running CKAN 2.0 or later, you can delete them harmlessly.

I'm afraid I don't recognize 'default'.

Comment: default is apperantly the default sysadmin user
and thank you very much